# Tkinter Callback and Trace Back Issue and Jupyter Notebook Issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

So the below is a GUI interface using Tkinter where I'm trying to call basic functions after pressing the button, the issue is that when I'm executing this in the Jupyter Notebook, the program works flawlessly.
but when I try to run is as a script(.py) file it's giving an error in the command shell

**Query 1 - How to resolve this below since I'm not able to figure out the error, I'm guessing I'm not passing an argument here?**

**Query 2 - Why no error coming in Jupyter Notebook and error happening in Python shell?**

I'm using Python 2.7

*Note:-  I was facing NumPy not getting imported error in Python 3.7 and 3.8 so I had to switch to a lower version of python to resolve that (couldn't deinstall and install NumPy since its an office laptop with no admin right)*

**Python Shell Error:**

```
error received
2402:8100:5::1600
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1541, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Papa\Python\IPV6_Final_V2.py", line 585, in excel_import
    import_exl()
  File "D:\Papa\Python\IPV6_Final_V2.py", line 475, in import_exl
    XML_Print()
  File "D:\Papa\Python\IPV6_Final_V2.py", line 27, in XML_Print
    mytree.write( export_dir +"/"+ str(MRBTS) +'_IPV6.xml',encoding='UTF-8')
NameError: global name 'export_dir' is not defined
```

**Code:**

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog as filedialog
#from Tkinter import filedialog
import tkMessageBox as messagebox
#from Tkinter import messagebox

Regen=Tk()
#Title for the window
Regen.title("VIL Regen Tool")

#Color Backgroud for the window

Regen.configure(bg="grey")

#Geometry for the window (300x300 defines the size + value defines the position in x and y axis)

Regen.geometry("300x300+500+200")

#Labeling
mylabel1=Label(text="VIL Regen Tool",fg="orange",bg="grey",font="Times 15 bold").pack()
mylabel1=Label(text="Developed by Sushanto Banerjee",fg="orange",bg="grey",font="Times 15 bold").place(x=10,y=100)

def xml_import():
    global xml_file
    xml_file=filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=[("XML files","*.xml")])
    label1=Label(text="XML Backup Imported").place(x=100,y=240)
    import_xml()
def excel_import():
    global excel_file
    excel_file=filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files","*.xlsx")])
    label2=Label(text="IP Plan Imported").place(x=120,y=270)
    import_exl()
def export():
    global export_dir
    export_dir=filedialog.askdirectory()
    mess=messagebox.showinfo(title="XML Generated",message="XMl generated")
    command=Regen.destroy()
    
button=Button(text="Import XML Backup",width=30,command=xml_import).pack()
button=Button(text="Import Excel IP Plan",width=30,command=excel_import).pack()
button=Button(text="Generate",width=30,command=export).pack()

Regen.mainloop()


def XML_Print():
    
    # Replacing the Vlues with IPV6 and writing it in XML


    for child in myroot.findall('.//{raml21.xsd}p'):
        parameter=child.attrib
        values=child.text
        for key in parameter:
    #Replacing GTPU IP
            if parameter[key]=="sgwIpAddress":
                new_values={'sgwIpAddress':'2402:8100:5::1600'}

                for key in new_values:
                    child.text=new_values['sgwIpAddress']
                    print (child.text)
    #                mytree.write('C:\output.xml',encoding='UTF-8')

                    mytree.write( export_dir +"/"+ str(MRBTS) +'_IPV6.xml',encoding='UTF-8')
```

I'm using Python 2.7

*Note:-  I was facing NumPy not getting imported error in Python 3.7 and 3.8 so I had to switch to a lower version of python to resolve that (couldn't deinstall and install NumPy since its an office laptop with no admin right)*

**Numpy import error below**

```
>>> import numpy
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:140: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.7 from "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.18.1" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

**Numpy installation Confirmation**

```
(base) PS C:\Users\Sushanto.Banerjee> pip show numpy
Name: numpy
Version: 1.18.1
Summary: NumPy is the fundamental package for array computing with Python.
Home-page: https://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: tables, statsmodels, seaborn, scipy, scikit-learn, PyWavelets, pytest-arraydiff, patsy, pandas, numexpr, numba, mkl-random, mkl-fft, matplotlib, imageio, h5py, Bottleneck, bokeh, bkcharts, astropy
(base) PS C:\Users\Sushanto.Banerjee>
```

Comment: BTW: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) . Use `lower_case_names` for variable - ie. `regen`. Use spaces around `=` when you assign to variables - i. `label1 = Label(...)`

Comment: error show you line which makes problem - `mytree.write( export_dir  ...)` - but you don't have this line in your code. You show wrong code. We can't help you. It seems  you run different code then you expect.

Comment: I have update the code ,since its pretty length i havent pasted the entire this just the pert where the error is occuring if u want i can paste the entire this also?

Answer (score 0):

OK so after you pointed out the line where the error was coming i retraced it and found that the function i was calling had some dependent variable which was causing the issue
below is what my final result looks like,thanks

```
#from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog as filedialog
#from Tkinter import filedialog
import tkMessageBox as messagebox
#from Tkinter import messagebox

Regen=Tk()
#Title for the window
Regen.title("VIL Regen Tool")

#Color Backgroud for the window

Regen.configure(bg="grey")

#Geometry for the window (300x300 defines the size + value defines the position in x and y axis)

Regen.geometry("300x300+500+200")

#Labeling
mylabel1=Label(text="VIL Regen Tool",fg="orange",bg="grey",font="Times 15 bold").pack()
mylabel1=Label(text="Developed by Sushanto Banerjee",fg="orange",bg="grey",font="Times 15 bold").place(x=10,y=100)

def xml_import():
    global xml_file
    xml_file=filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=[("XML files","*.xml")])
    label1=Label(text="XML Backup Imported").place(x=100,y=240)
    import_xml()
def excel_import():
    global excel_file
    excel_file=filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files","*.xlsx")])
    label2=Label(text="IP Plan Imported").place(x=120,y=270)
    import_exl()
def export():
    global export_dir
    export_dir=filedialog.askdirectory()
    mess=messagebox.showinfo(title="XML Generated",message="XMl generated")
    XML_Print()
    command=Regen.destroy()
```

Comment: i am still tryin to find the issue for the 2nd query as to why no errors were coming in jupyter while i was running the same code in python its giving numpy import error

Comment: if you have new error then create new question and show **full** error message. OR maybe you forgot to install `numpy` on your computer. Jupyter may use different Python which has `nympy` already installed.

Comment: so iv edited the above query with numpy error and confirmation that numpy is present,iv tried deinstallation of the library but because of admin rights isue its not happening,my only issue is since its already installaed shouldnt it be working ?

Comment: did uou try advice with using full path to Python ? You may have installed two Pythons and it can make problem - maybe it runs different Python and it has problem.

Comment: Can you explan "full path ",cuz i dont have clarity as ho to to assign that,and yes i did install Python 2 previously,then i installed python 3.7,3.6.....do u think this is causing the issue ?

Comment: I mean full path to python when you run script `"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe  script.py` If  you have installed many Pythons then short command `python.exe` may run different version then you installed modules. You can check version `python.exe -V`. You can also use it to install modules - `python.exe -m pip install numpy` and it will install module for this version.

Comment: i deinstalled numpy and reinstalled it in another pc,seems to be working,issue was of multiple python being installed only,i removed the remining python only have 2.7 installed its working like a charm now thank u so much for the help